# UICollectionView Mayhem

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, ios7

So i have a UICollectionView which i subclassed to get data from my datamodel.

There are two different types of cells for two different types of data. Currently only the top cell(wider) needs to be used.

The cells should look like this:

[image]

But when I run it in the simulator it looks like this:

[image]

Anybody have any ideas as to why? I haven't implemented a custom layout here.... Yet.... I am assuming i must do that....

Is there anything i need to do special if i have different sizes for each cell?

Comment: looks like layout issue. did you try changing autosizing settings?

Comment: Please include more detail. What sort of layout object are you using? If its a flow layout, what have you done for setting the size or implementing the delegate methods?

Comment: Actually I figured it out. For some reason the cells would just default to the smallest cell size. I implemented the delegate method

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: Please scale your images down a bit...